# Do where in all subqueries or on main query?

Tags: mysql, performance

Should I do a `WHERE` in each subquery, or just on main query? My question is about performance. For instance:

**WHERE in all subqueries**:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE id_user = :id_user

UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE id_user = :id_user
```

In this case, each subquery will have the *same* `WHERE` clause, filtering by `id_user`.

**WHERE only on main query**:

```
SELECT 
    SUBQUERY.*

FROM (
    SELECT ..., id_user
    FROM ...

    UNION ALL
    SELECT ..., id_user
    FROM ...
) AS SUBQUERY

WHERE SUBQUERY.id_user = :id_user
```

In this case, each subquery will return the `id_user`, so main query will get it and will filter.

---

In my mind, the first one will be faster, because it'll filter first, union, and return all. In second case, it'll find all, union, and filter. The advantage of second method is that I'll write the `WHERE`a single time -- imagine that I have 10 similar subqueries.

**But the question is: will MySQL be capable to optimize it?**

Comment: Have you looked at your execution plan?

Comment: Defiantly the first one, especially if you going to be working with a highly reduced result set in your inner query(s).

Comment: It'll result in most time up to ~25 rows. But will query over 100.000 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL materializes subqueries.  That means that the subqueries are fully processed, before subsequent processing takes place.

So, in MySQL, you should put the `where` clause in the subqueries, to reduce the volume of data and speed the query.  Your first version should have better performance than the second.

Also, you can remove the outer query for the first version.  Just do:

```
(SELECT ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE id_user = :id_user
) UNION ALL
(SELECT ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE id_user = :id_user
)
```

This is not true in most other databases.

Comment: Thanks. My outer query is to `ORDER BY`, but really is not relevant to this question. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRodrigues . . . Actually, you can add an `order by` to `union all` queries without a subquery.  However, the sorting requires storing all the data, so I don't think the overhead of materializing the subquery makes a difference.

Comment: `UNION` requires a tmp table (even `UNION ALL`); this is a inefficiency that is only now (5.7.3) being remedied.  `UNION DISTINCT` always(?) needs the tmp and sort.